# Making a background rectangle with different colors in android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Is there way to make and Android background have different colored sides by using `android:shape="rectangle"` ? Right now I have it set but all the side of my view are the same color.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941606/changing-gradient-background-colors-on-android-at-runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [gradient](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#gradient-element) color to fill your shape, meaning one side will have one color and the other side will have another color, with the color blending between the two sides.

A way to have 4 sides with different colors is use a [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) drawable, this isn't a shape anymore.