# Gradient relative to screen size

Tags: android, android-drawable

Suppose that I have a drawable .xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:centerX="0.5"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:endColor="#ff2222bb"
    android:gradientRadius="400"
    android:startColor="#ff6666ff"
    android:type="radial" />

<corners android:radius="50dp" />
```

I use this as background of my main layout.

Now my problem is that the "400" is an absolute value, that does not depend from density, nor size of the screen. The result is that on small phones and on table the graphical rendering of this xml is pretty different.

Is there a way to link the gradientRadius to the size of the screen, so that the drawable appears equal on all screens?

thanks.

Comment: I sure you have already seen the other stackoverflow answer explaining that the percentage sign only divides by 100 the value an is not actually a real % as one could expect. I put this if someone new lands here one day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176590/gradient-radius-as-percentage-of-screen-size

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is you can use percentage to set the gradient radius size. Android doc says:

> [android:gradientRadius](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:gradientRadius)
>
> May be a fractional value, which is a
> floating point number appended with either % or %p, such as "14.5%".
> The % suffix always means a percentage of the base size; the optional
> %p suffix provides a size relative to some parent container.

Comment: Unfortunately the % is not accepted in that field, it only likes intergers.

Comment: Oh I checked your documentation, actually you're correct but it does not seem to work... strange!

Comment: Percentage works on Lollipop only, at least from my tests this is the behavior. For pre-Lollipop versions you have to set it programmatically or through different dimen values.