# Integer Resources And Shape Drawables

Tags: android, resources, gradient, shapes

I am trying to give different gradientRadius values to a gradient object via an integer resource but it does not take any effect. Gradient is not drawn. Can't we use integer resources in shapes defined in xml? I have two resource files(integer.xml) located under values and values-land folders. `gradient_radius` has different values for each file.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="6px"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#FFFDEDBE"
        android:centerColor="#CCE5D4AE"
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="@integer/gradient_radius"
        android:startColor="#5568675A" />

</shape>
```

Comment: can you please post both value ? or Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176590/gradient-radius-as-percentage-of-screen-size

Comment: the one in values folder is 50 and the other one is 100. Both of them are integer and i expect them to be evaluated as 50px and 100px as people mentioned on the link you provided but no gradient is drawn in my case.