# changing values of a drawable background

Tags: java, android

hello what i want to do is setting a value in a `drawable` file bg.xml 
here is the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffc2e59c"
                android:centerColor="#ff3a7a7a"
                android:endColor="#ff3a7a7a"
                android:angle="135"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

i want to change `android:startColor="#ffc2e59c"` if a file exists . ( i already know using if to make it use the line . )
so what i want to do is

```
    my lines {  

    if (filee.exists()) {

    change the color to something else 
    (android:startColor="#ffffffff")
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you use it in the background of an xml object now?

Comment: yes :) android:background=@drawable/bg i use this as a background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper way of getting this done is like this:

```
File f = new File("cbc.db");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    int h = v.getHeight();
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h, Color.parseColor("#330000FF"), Color.parseColor("#110000FF"), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
}
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941606/changing-gradient-background-colors-on-android-at-runtime) for more information.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean with "the file" do you mean the resource file exists? because this solution doesn't use a resource file.

Comment: no . a file name cdc.db located in a folder . i already can check the file but only i need to config the "if l" line :))

Answer (score 0):

you could just create another drawable and pragmatically add that as the background as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android)