# How to design EditText and Button in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-button

How can I design my `EditText` and `Button` like in the `Instagram` application? I understand that I would need to do this by using `Drawable` files but every link I have found only shows how to design using `Gradients` which looks horrible. I just want something simple but not sure where to start.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is create a `Button` or `Edittext` or `TextView` with transparent background and colored border like:

activity code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorpink">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Transparent Button with blue border"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_button_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`transparent_button_selector.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- pressed state -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners  android:radius="22dp" />

</shape></item>

<!-- focused state -->
<item android:state_focused="true"><shape>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="22dp" />

</shape></item>
<!-- normal state -->
<item><shape>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="22dp" />

</shape></item>
</selector>
```

colors :

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorpink">#AAFF4081</color>
```

And its looking like :

[image]

You can change `transparent_button_selector.xml` , change colors, radius values, borders and try to create your layout firstly and then think about background. Yes i will say gradient too . There is one question here for it : [changing-gradient-background-colors-on-android-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941606/changing-gradient-background-colors-on-android-at-runtime)

Also you can play with backgorund color, if you use few transparent white like `#33FFFFFF` then the result will be like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLdWH.jpg

Comment: Thank you! That worked great! I also used your example to help me out with the EditText and they look great as well!

Comment: Good to hear that , im here for that purpose and i am happy then. Thank you too have a good day !

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they are using a single gradient `drawable` for the background of the login layout and then the `EditTexts` have a mostly-transparent white background and the `Button` has a fully transparent background.  To round the corners of the `EditText`/`Button`, set the background to a drawable that looks something like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners 
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="2dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

may be this code can help you. This is the activity.xml file. use `TextView` as `Button`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF929999">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:hint="username"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:paddingLeft="16.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="16.0dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#b3ffffff"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ccffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`input_field.xml` file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#1affffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="2.0dip"/>
</shape>
```

And `button_border.xml` will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#1affffff"/>
            <stroke 
                 android:width="1.0dip"
                 android:color="#80ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="2.0dip"/>
        </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
          <stroke 
              android:width="1.0dip" 
              android:color="#33ffffff"/>
          <corners android:radius="2.0dip"/>
      </shape>
   </item>
```

enjoy the design.

Comment: this is a nice background just look like instagram app

Comment: Exactly like instagram, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Drawable with border and transparent color for EditText and Button, and the entire violet background is image, not gradient drawable. And also use TransitionDrawable for transitioning between two drawables like Instagram.